# Удалить одинаковые значения из ассоциативного массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Имеется ас. массив вида

```
data: [
                 {
                    "category": "K_01",
                    "value": "15847"
                 },
                 {
                    "category": "K_02",
                    "value": "124232"
                 },
                 {
                    "category": "K_21",
                    "value": "2342"
                 },
                 {
                    "category": "K_21",
                    "value": "2342"
                 },
                 {
                    "category": "K_21",
                    "value": "2342"
                 },
             ]
```

каким образом можно удалить повторяющиеся элементы? в итоге соответственно должно остаться K_01, K_02, K_21

Comment: Это обычный массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [{
  "category": "K_01",
  "value": "15847"
}, {
  "category": "K_02",
  "value": "124232"
}, {
  "category": "K_21",
  "value": "2342"
}, {
  "category": "K_21",
  "value": "2342"
}, {
  "category": "K_21",
  "value": "2342"
}];

var unique = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (unique.indexOf(data[i].category) >= 0) {
    data.splice(i, 1);
    i--;
  } else {
    unique.push(data[i].category);
  }
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно заменить ключ у конкретного элемента массива? например для 3 элемента вместо ключа "value" записать ключ "summary"?

Comment: В какой момент его нужно заменить? Перед запуском скрипта или в процессе его выполнения?

Answer (score 2):

больше инфы про Set https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

```
let data = [{
  "category": "K_01",
  "value": "15847"
}, {
  "category": "K_02",
  "value": "124232"
}, {
  "category": "K_21",
  "value": "2342"
}, {
  "category": "K_21",
  "value": "2342"
}, {
  "category": "K_21",
  "value": "2342"
}];

data = Array.from(new Set(data.map(JSON.stringify))).map(JSON.parse);
console.log(data);
```